# ZPL Utf-8 characters dissapearing

Tags: encoding, utf-8, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I've encountered a problem when trying to print a simple ZPL string.
My ZPL contains some UTF-8 characters like so:

```
^XA
^FT16,591^A0N,34^FH^FVM_F6lntorp^FS
^FT16,626^A0N,34^FH^FVV_E4gen^FS
^XZ
```

This should print out `Mölntorp` (_F6 = ö) and `Vägen` (_E4 = ä). And it does.

**BUT**, here comes the problem, I tried adding a danish ø (_F8 = ø), like so:

```
^XA
^FT16,626^A0N,34^FH^FVK_F8benhavnsvej
^XZ
```

But what comes out is `K°benhavnsvej` (which corresponds to _F8 = ° in **CP-850**). I have no clue why it successfully translates one hex code and then mucks up on the other one, since they should both be using the same encoding table. (None specified)

If I add `^CI28` below the starting `^XA` tag, the UTF-8 characters simply vanish, and the output is just `Kbenhavnsvej`

I hope someone could give me input on why this is happening. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

```
^XA
^FT16,626^CI4^A0N,34^FH^FVK_7Cbenhavnsvej
^XZ
```

I haven't tried this - but it should work in theory.

`^CI4` selects international character set for Denmark; character 7C should be the character you require (5C for upper-case)

Answer (score 0):

This may also be the font you are using, the font simply might not contain this in its character set. You may have to use the Swiss Eastern European font.